# ExtAudioFileOpenURL & AVAudioFile unable to read .aac file

Tags: swift, avfoundation, wav, aac

I'm currently making a swift app that records an aac file from an [audiostream](https://archives.kdvs.org/stream) and uses shazamKit to identify the song. The stream itself plays back audio in the aac format which is why I download it as a .aac file (NOT of .m4a or mp3) but shazamKit reads in a .wav file which requires me to make a .aac to .wav converter function.

The recording part of my code works fine but every which way I try to open this .aac file (ExtAudioFileOpenURL or AVFile) I get the same 4 errors:

```
2023-07-22 09:58:55.795711+0900 KDVS[46452:2598649]  ReadBytes Failed
2023-07-22 09:58:55.795818+0900 KDVS[46452:2598649]  AACAudioFile::ParseAudioFile failed
2023-07-22 09:58:55.795911+0900 KDVS[46452:2598649]  OpenFromDataSource failed
2023-07-22 09:58:55.795977+0900 KDVS[46452:2598649]  Open failed
2023-07-22 09:58:55.796073+0900 KDVS[46452:2598649] [default]          ExtAudioFile.cpp:210
```

I thought maybe the file is corrupted, but when I play the .aac file in any media player it works perfectly fine. Then I thought maybe the file URL isn't correct, so I wrote a print statement which prints the URL and T/F if the (fileExists(at: inputURL) at that returns true every time. The permissions should be fine too because the file is located in the Documents library

"file:///Users/johncarraher/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/273C3EEA-823C-4A15-A67A-7DE5D5463AB5/data/Containers/Data/Application/A86A9BA4-F2EA-4D10-A93A-5C0F58690E8A/Documents/recording.aac".

I'm not too familiar with audiofile encodings so I'm not sure where to go from here, but I think either my file is a little corrupted or .aac files are not supported by most "AudioFile" readers. I have attached the class in my code that records the stream, and my aactowav converter function. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

```
//
//  aactowav.swift
//  KDVS
//
//  Created by John Carraher on 7/21/23.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

func convertAACtoWAV(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL) {
    var error: OSStatus = noErr

    var destinationFile: ExtAudioFileRef? = nil

    var sourceFile: ExtAudioFileRef? = nil

    var srcFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    var dstFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()

    print("6 About to open \(inputURL) which has a status of \(fileExists(at: inputURL)) which looks like this: \(inputURL as CFURL) as a CFURL")
    
    ExtAudioFileOpenURL(inputURL as CFURL, &sourceFile) //**Line where error comes from**
    print("7")

    var thePropertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: srcFormat))

    ExtAudioFileGetProperty(sourceFile!,
                            kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                            &thePropertySize, &srcFormat)

    dstFormat.mSampleRate = 44100 // Set sample rate
    dstFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
    dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    dstFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16
    dstFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2 * dstFormat.mChannelsPerFrame
    dstFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1
    dstFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger

    // Create destination file
    error = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
        outputURL as CFURL,
        kAudioFileWAVEType,
        &dstFormat,
        nil,
        AudioFileFlags.eraseFile.rawValue,
        &destinationFile)
    print("Error 1 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(sourceFile!,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat)
    print("Error 2 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")

    error = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(destinationFile!,
                                    kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                    thePropertySize,
                                    &dstFormat)
    print("Error 3 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")

    let bufferByteSize: UInt32 = 32768
    var srcBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(bufferByteSize))
    var sourceFrameOffset: ULONG = 0

    while true {
        var fillBufList = AudioBufferList(
            mNumberBuffers: 1,
            mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
                mNumberChannels: 2,
                mDataByteSize: bufferByteSize,
                mData: &srcBuffer
            )
        )
        var numFrames: UInt32 = 0

        if dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame > 0 {
            numFrames = bufferByteSize / dstFormat.mBytesPerFrame
        }

        error = ExtAudioFileRead(sourceFile!, &numFrames, &fillBufList)
        print("Error 4 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")

        if numFrames == 0 {
            error = noErr
            break
        }

        sourceFrameOffset += numFrames
        error = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile!, numFrames, &fillBufList)
        print("Error 5 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")
    }

    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(destinationFile!)
    print("Error 6 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")
    error = ExtAudioFileDispose(sourceFile!)
    print("Error 7 in convertAACtoWAV: \(error.description)")
}

func fileExists(at url: URL) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    return fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path)
}
```

```
//
//  CachingPlayerItem.swift
//  KDVS
//
//  Created by John Carraher on 7/20/23.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

fileprivate extension URL {
    
    func withScheme(_ scheme: String) -> URL? {
        var components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        components?.scheme = scheme
        return components?.url
    }
    
}

@objc protocol CachingPlayerItemDelegate {
    
    /// Is called when the media file is fully downloaded.
    @objc optional func playerItem(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem, didFinishDownloadingData data: Data)
    
    /// Is called every time a new portion of data is received.
    @objc optional func playerItem(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem, didDownloadBytesSoFar bytesDownloaded: Int, outOf bytesExpected: Int)
    
    /// Is called after initial prebuffering is finished, means
    /// we are ready to play.
    @objc optional func playerItemReadyToPlay(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem)
    
    /// Is called when the data being downloaded did not arrive in time to
    /// continue playback.
    @objc optional func playerItemPlaybackStalled(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem)
    
    /// Is called on downloading error.
    @objc optional func playerItem(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem, downloadingFailedWith error: Error)
}

open class CachingPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    
    class ResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
        
        var playingFromData = false
        var mimeType: String? // is required when playing from Data
        var session: URLSession?
        var mediaData: Data?
        var response: URLResponse?
        var pendingRequests = Set<AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest>()
        weak var owner: CachingPlayerItem?
        var fileURL: URL!
        var outputStream: OutputStream?
        
        func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
            
            if playingFromData {
                
                // Nothing to load.
                
            } else if session == nil {
                
                // If we're playing from a url, we need to download the file.
                // We start loading the file on first request only.
                guard let initialUrl = owner?.url else {
                    fatalError("internal inconsistency")
                }

                startDataRequest(with: initialUrl)
            }
            
            pendingRequests.insert(loadingRequest)
            processPendingRequests()
            return true
            
        }
        
        func startDataRequest(with url: URL) {
                
                var recordingName = "record.mp3"
                if let recording = owner?.recordingName{
                    recordingName = recording
                }
                
                //Find Documents Directory (If it don't exist, don't create it)
                fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                    .appendingPathComponent(recordingName)
                
                // Check if the file already exists
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                    do {
                        // Clear the contents of the existing file
                        try Data().write(to: fileURL)
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed to clear existing file data: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
                let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
                session?.dataTask(with: url).resume()
                outputStream = OutputStream(url: fileURL, append: true)
                outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
                outputStream?.open()
                
            }
        
        func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) {
            pendingRequests.remove(loadingRequest)
        }
        
        // MARK: URLSession delegate
        
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
            let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes{outputStream?.write($0, maxLength: data.count)}
        }
        
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow)
            mediaData = Data()
            self.response = response
            processPendingRequests()
        }
        
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
                if let errorUnwrapped = error {
                    owner?.delegate?.playerItem?(owner!, downloadingFailedWith: errorUnwrapped)
                    return
                }
            }
        // MARK: -
        
        func processPendingRequests() {
            
            // get all fullfilled requests
            let requestsFulfilled = Set<AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest>(pendingRequests.compactMap {
                self.fillInContentInformationRequest($0.contentInformationRequest)
                if self.haveEnoughDataToFulfillRequest($0.dataRequest!) {
                    $0.finishLoading()
                    return $0
                }
                return nil
            })
        
            // remove fulfilled requests from pending requests
            _ = requestsFulfilled.map { self.pendingRequests.remove($0) }

        }
        
        func fillInContentInformationRequest(_ contentInformationRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest?) {
            if playingFromData {
                contentInformationRequest?.contentType = self.mimeType
                contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = Int64(mediaData!.count)
                contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
                return
            }
            
            guard let responseUnwrapped = response else {
                // have no response from the server yet
                return
            }
            
            contentInformationRequest?.contentType = responseUnwrapped.mimeType
            contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = responseUnwrapped.expectedContentLength
            contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
            
        }
        
        func haveEnoughDataToFulfillRequest(_ dataRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest) -> Bool {
            
            let requestedOffset = Int(dataRequest.requestedOffset)
            let requestedLength = dataRequest.requestedLength
            let currentOffset = Int(dataRequest.currentOffset)
            
            guard let songDataUnwrapped = mediaData,
                songDataUnwrapped.count > currentOffset else {
                return false
            }
            
            let bytesToRespond = min(songDataUnwrapped.count - currentOffset, requestedLength)
            let dataToRespond = songDataUnwrapped.subdata(in: Range(uncheckedBounds: (currentOffset, currentOffset + bytesToRespond)))
            dataRequest.respond(with: dataToRespond)
            
            return songDataUnwrapped.count >= requestedLength + requestedOffset
            
        }
        
        deinit {
            session?.invalidateAndCancel()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    fileprivate let resourceLoaderDelegate = ResourceLoaderDelegate()
    fileprivate let url: URL
    fileprivate let initialScheme: String?
    fileprivate var customFileExtension: String?
    
    
    weak var delegate: CachingPlayerItemDelegate?
    
    func stopDownloading(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        resourceLoaderDelegate.session?.invalidateAndCancel()
        completion()
    }
    
    // Function to get the URL of the downloaded file
    func getDownloadedFileURL() -> URL? {
        if resourceLoaderDelegate.playingFromData {
            // If playing from Data, return the URL created for fake data
            return resourceLoaderDelegate.fileURL
        } else {
            // If playing from URL, return the URL of the downloaded file
            return try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                .appendingPathComponent(recordingName)
        }
    }
    
    open func download() {
        if resourceLoaderDelegate.session == nil {
            resourceLoaderDelegate.startDataRequest(with: url)
        }
    }
    
    private let cachingPlayerItemScheme = "cachingPlayerItemScheme"
    var recordingName = "record.mp3"
    /// Is used for playing remote files.
    convenience init(url: URL, recordingName: String) {
        self.init(url: url, customFileExtension: nil, recordingName: recordingName)
    }
    
    /// Override/append custom file extension to URL path.
    /// This is required for the player to work correctly with the intended file type.
    init(url: URL, customFileExtension: String?, recordingName: String) {
        
        guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false),
            let scheme = components.scheme,
            var urlWithCustomScheme = url.withScheme(cachingPlayerItemScheme) else {
            fatalError("Urls without a scheme are not supported")
        }
        self.recordingName = recordingName
        self.url = url
        self.initialScheme = scheme
        
        if let ext = customFileExtension {
            urlWithCustomScheme.deletePathExtension()
            urlWithCustomScheme.appendPathExtension(ext)
            self.customFileExtension = ext
        }
        
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: urlWithCustomScheme)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(resourceLoaderDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        super.init(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: nil)
        
        resourceLoaderDelegate.owner = self
        
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playbackStalledHandler), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self)
        
    }
    
    /// Is used for playing from Data.
    init(data: Data, mimeType: String, fileExtension: String) {
        
        guard let fakeUrl = URL(string: cachingPlayerItemScheme + "://whatever/file.\(fileExtension)") else {
            fatalError("internal inconsistency")
        }
        
        self.url = fakeUrl
        self.initialScheme = nil
        
        resourceLoaderDelegate.mediaData = data
        resourceLoaderDelegate.playingFromData = true
        resourceLoaderDelegate.mimeType = mimeType
        
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: fakeUrl)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(resourceLoaderDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        super.init(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: nil)
        resourceLoaderDelegate.owner = self
        
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playbackStalledHandler), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: KVO
    
    override open func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        delegate?.playerItemReadyToPlay?(self)
    }
    
    // MARK: Notification hanlers
    
    @objc func playbackStalledHandler() {
        delegate?.playerItemPlaybackStalled?(self)
    }

    // MARK: -
    
    override init(asset: AVAsset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: [String]?) {
        fatalError("not implemented")
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
        resourceLoaderDelegate.session?.invalidateAndCancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my .aac file was incorrectly formatted. Since I downloaded from an audiostream, the program immediately started writing to the file, ignoring the structure of each frame and more importantly the header. As a result most of the metadata for the audio was in the file, but couldn't be read because it wasn't at the very front (my file in hex read EB3B, but had a FFF1 a couple hundred bits after). The fix was to make a function that deleted any data before the first header (signaled by FFF1). The function I used to re-format the .aac is below:

```
func deleteBeforeMarkerFFF1(inputURL: URL, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    do {
        // Read the AAC audio file as binary data
        var inputData = try Data(contentsOf: inputURL)

        // Find the position of the marker "FFF1"
        guard let markerRange = inputData.range(of: Data([0xFF, 0xF1])) else {
            completion()
            return
        }

        // Remove all data before the marker "FFF1"
        let trimmedData = inputData.subdata(in: markerRange.lowerBound..<inputData.endIndex)

        // Replace the original binary data with the modified binary data
        inputData = trimmedData

        // Write the modified binary data back to the AAC audio file
        try inputData.write(to: inputURL)

        completion()
    } catch {
        // Handle the error here
        print("Error: \(error)")
        completion()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `mimeType` is not correctly received or processed. I would try to set it manually. Then the rest of your code may work.

```
func fillInContentInformationRequest(_ contentInformationRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest?) {
            if playingFromData {
                contentInformationRequest?.contentType = self.mimeType
                contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = Int64(mediaData!.count)
                contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
                return
            }
            
            guard let responseUnwrapped = response else {
                // have no response from the server yet
                return
            }
            
            // contentInformationRequest?.contentType = responseUnwrapped.mimeType
print("responseUnwrapped.mimeType:", responseUnwrapped.mimeType)

contentInformationRequest?.contentType = "audio/aac"

contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = responseUnwrapped.expectedContentLength
            contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
            
        }
```

Comment: Actually I adjust my previous comment, this code, printed out "responseUnwrapped.mimeType: Optional("audio/aac")", yet the file it spit out was still identified as am "application/octet-stream" mimetype file. Maybe I set it somewhere after? Or maybe this isn't even directly setting the mimetype?

Comment: Yes, you set the contentInformationRequest.mimeType, but it is not used further anywhere!

Comment: Try to set `ResourceLoaderDelegate` `var mimeType: String? = "audio/aac"`

Comment: Tried doing this in the init function, but no luck, still says its an octet stream